# How to return correctly cast IEnumerable

Tags: c#, generics, casting

This method works, except it returns List`<object`> when what I really want is List`<Resource`> when specificType is Resource (and List`<YYY`> when specificType is YYY, and so on).

How can I rearrange the method signature to return List`<specificType`>?  Then, is there a better way to do this?  The items in List`<object`> are deserialized from many different types in this assembly.  I'm trying to create lists of ActualType and return that list to caller.  Hope this makes sense.

```
private static ICollection<object> GetSpecificTypeList(Dictionary<string, List<object>> objectListDictionary, Type specificType)
{
    Contract.Requires(objectListDictionary != null);
    Contract.Requires(specificType != null);

    var typeFullName = specificType.FullName;
    var typedCollection = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(specificType));
    var collection = objectListDictionary.SingleOrDefault(q => q.Key.Equals(typeFullName)).Value;
    foreach (var obj in collection)
    {
        typedCollection.Add(Convert.ChangeType(obj, specificType));
    }

    return collection;
}

var resourceList = GetSpecificTypeList(package.FilesDictionary, typeof(Resource));
```

Would dynamic help?

Comment: Why all the reflection? Why not just make it generic to begin with? `private static List<T> GetSpecificTypeList<T>(Dictionary<string, List<object>> objectListDictionary) { ... }`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the method generic:

```
private static ICollection<T> GetSpecificTypeList<T>(Dictionary<string, List<object>> objectListDictionary)
{
    Contract.Requires(objectListDictionary != null);
    Contract.Requires(specificType != null);

    var list = new List<T>();
    var collection = objectListDictionary.SingleOrDefault(q => q.Key.Equals(typeof(T).FullName)).Value;
    foreach (var obj in collection.OfType<T>())
    {
        list.Add(obj);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: I think `Dictionary<string, List<object>> objectListDictionary` should be `Dictionary<string, List<T>> objectListDictionary`

Comment: @JamesR. The object he's passing in (`package.FilesDictionary`) is a `Dictionary<string, List<object>>`

Comment: @DaveZych but considering taking Stanley's suggestion below to pass Dictionary<Type, List<object>>

Comment: @RobertKerr I would advise that if you can do it.

Comment: @DaveZych should be another ) after FullName (and fix capitalization)

Comment: How would I change the call to this?  var resourceList = GetSpecificTypeList<Resource>(package.FilesDictionary);  gives an assignment error.

Comment: @RobertKerr what's the exact type of `FilesDictionary`?

Comment: @DaveZych public Dictionary<string, ICollection<object>> FilesDictionary { get; set; }    -- but willing to change to public Dictionary<Type, ICollection<object>> FilesDictionary { get; set; }  but first I'd like to get the correct call to the above answer before refactoring.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it by changing parameter type to Dictionary<string, ICollection<object>>.  Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I rearrange the method signature to return `List<specificType>`?

Make the method generic:

```
private static ICollection<T> GetSpecificTypeList<T>(Dictionary<string, List<object>> objectListDictionary)
{
    Contract.Requires(objectListDictionary != null);
    Contract.Requires(specificType != null);

    var typeFullName = typeof(T).FullName;
    //var collection = objectListDictionary.SingleOrDefault(q => q.Key.Equals(typeFullName)).Value;
    var collection = objectListDictionary[typeFullName];
    var typedCollection = collection.OfType<T>().ToList();

    return typedCollection;
}
```

Now your calling syntax is:

```
var resourceList = GetSpecificTypeList<Resource>(package.FilesDictionary);
```

A few other suggestions:

- Consider a `Dictionary<Type, List<object>` instead - using s atring to identify a type can be tricky
- You may even be able to use `List<object>` and filter using `list.OfType<T>` (assuming that the key for each object collection is its type.

Comment: Thanks for the additional suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my modified version of Dave's propsal using yield return and IEnumerable, which enables lazy evaluation:

```
private static IEnumerable<T> GetSpecificTypeList<T>(Dictionary<string, List<object>> objectListDictionary)
{
    Contract.Requires(objectListDictionary != null);
    var collection = objectListDictionary.SingleOrDefault(q => q.Key.Equals(typeof(T).ToString())).Value;
    foreach (var obj in collection)
    {
        yield return (T) Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(T));
    }
}
```